# Postfix for CMake build and install directories names

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I'd like to have a script which adds postfix for directories names (CMake project with Qt dependencies).
For example, let's assume that we have environment variable

```
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="d:\qt\official\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\lib\cmake".
```

Sometimes I don't set generator name, so CMake uses the default one.
I'd like to have automatic postfixes which shows toolset and Qt version:
my_app-*build*-**qt5.15.2-msvc2019_64** and my_app-*bin*-**qt5.15.2-msvc2019_64** (I don't need strict correspondence, just to distinguish between different builds). So, I'd like to have a possibility to change Qt version/toolset easily and avoid hard-coded postfixes (on-the-fly postfix generation). I'd like to extract used Qt and toolset version used for building my application. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

To generate postfixes for your directory names in CMake based on the Qt version and toolset, you can use Python script in conjunction with CMake. Here's a breakdown of how to achieve this:

CMake Code

```
set(ENV{CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} "d:\qt\official\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\lib\cmake")

execute_process(
    COMMAND python "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/generate_postfix.py"
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE POSTFIX
)

set(MY_APP_BUILD_DIR "my_app-build-${POSTFIX}")
set(MY_APP_BIN_DIR "my_app-bin-${POSTFIX}")

# Further actions in your CMake projects using MY_APP_BUILD_DIR and MY_APP_BIN_DIR
```

generage_postfix.py

```py
import os
import re

def extract_versions():
    cmake_prefix_path = os.environ.get("CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH", "")
    qt_version = re.search(rf'qt(?:{os.path.sep}(?:\w+?{os.path.sep})?)?(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)', cmake_prefix_path)
    toolset = re.search(r'msvc\d+_\d+', cmake_prefix_path)

    qt_version_str = qt_version.group(1) if qt_version else ""
    toolset_str = toolset.group(0) if toolset else ""

    return f"qt{qt_version_str}-{toolset_str}" if qt_version_str and toolset_str else ""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    postfix = extract_versions()
    print(postfix)
```